# SQL statement quotation

Tags: sql, asp.net

I need help with my SQL statement quotation, can someone please help me?

All the variables are integer

First one is:

```
var sqlSearch = "SELECT * FROM Profiles WHERE BodyType=" "+bodyType+ " OR   Education=" "+education+" OR Eyes =" "+eyes+" OR Hairs=" "+hairs+ " OR Heights    =" "+heights+" OR Religion =" +"religion+"";
```

Second one is :

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Profiles (MemberID, Description, Religion, HairColor, Eye, Education, Height, BodyType) VALUES ("+Session("MemberID")+", "+description+", "+religion+", "+hairs+", "+eyes+", "+education+", "+heights+", "+bodyType+")";
```

Comment: try this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: Are you building this string up in c#/vb or in SQL? to concatinate in MySQL you have to use the CONCAT function, for example: var sqlSearch = SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM Profiles WHERE BodyType=', bodyType, ' OR   Education=', education, ' OR Eyes =', eyes, ' OR Hairs=', hairs, ' OR Heights =', heights, ' OR Religion =', religion);

Comment: They are integer not string. I am using them in classical asp with an access database

Comment: By string I was referring to the SQL statement that is being stored in the variable sqlSearch. I've just realised that this is probably being built up prior to being passed to sql.. in which case ignore my previous comment..

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: I agree.. I was under the impression that the code was soley SQL and the params had already been passed, hence why I said ignore!

Answer (score 0):

```
var sqlSearch = "SELECT * FROM Profiles WHERE BodyType='"+bodyType+ "' OR   Education='" + education + "' OR Eyes ='"+eyes+"' OR Hairs ='"+ hairs + "' OR Heights ='"+heights+"' OR Religion ='" + religion+"'";

sql = "INSERT INTO Profiles (MemberID, Description, Religion, HairColor, Eye, Education, Height, BodyType) VALUES ('" + Session("MemberID")+"', '"+description+"', '"+religion +"', '"+hairs+"', '"+eyes+"', '"+education+"', '"+heights+"', '"+bodyType+"')";
```

Comment: by using the double quote for the variables, isn't it saying that they are string? They are int in my database

Comment: if you use double quote, you have to use double "double quote" insetad in T-SQL, so single quote is better solution, if it is int, you don't need single quote.

Comment: Sorry I meant single quote. Aren,t we using single quote when it's a string? But we don't have to use them when it's an integer?

Comment: Yes, if it is integer, we don't need to use single quote although it is works.

Comment: It should work except your string include single quote, if in this case, you have to replace it using single single quote. Replace(" ' "," ' ' ")